# React Developer Tools "Highlight Updates" has been removed, what alternatives exists?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

The debugging option "Highlight Updates" was regrettably removed in the new version 4.0.5 (8/19/2019). This option was an essential component for my daily working process to indicate rerender issue instantly.

I know there's an optimized Profiler available, but I still would like to keep an eye on the rerender during the working process.

So, are there any alternatives available, which provide the same functionality (displaying a rectangle on the (re)rendered components?
Or is there a way to downgrade the react devTools?

I already searched for a way to downgrade react devTools or a alternative npm package, which provides the same functionality; unfortunately without any success.

Comment: I see it was [already asked on SO](/questions/57563530) and there's an [issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16437). You can probably use the built-in [paint highlight](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/simplify-paint-complexity-and-reduce-paint-areas#use_chrome_devtools_to_quickly_identify_paint_bottlenecks) feature.

Comment: Thank you, don't know, why i did not find it by myself. So i will jump on the github issue and hope they will get this feature back.